# Who was mother of Subhadra? Rohini or Yashoda?

Tags: mahabharata, subhadra

In Star Plus serial, it is shown that Krishna is exchanged with daughter of Nand and Yashoda. When Kans tried to kill the exchanged daughter, she transforms into some other character and disappears. The character's face was same as Subhadra actor in the serial. So possibly they want to show it was Subhadra.

So based on that, Yashoda should be mother of Subhadra?

But when I searched and read on Wikipedia, found out that Rohini was mother of Subhadra.

What's the truth?

Comment: The one Kansa tried to kill was Yogmaya...may be less actors so serial offered two roles to one actor..

Answer (score 6):

The one Kansa tried to kill was Yogmaya, daughter of Yashoda.

However, Subhadra, wife of Arjuna was daughter of Rohini. It's reference can be found in [Harivamsham: Harivamsha Parva: Chapter 35](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/hv_1_35.html):

> chitrAM nAma kumArIM cha **rohiNI** tanayA dasha |
>
> chitrA subhadra iti punar-vikhyAtA kurunandana || 1-35-6
>
> O descendant of kuru, they [Vasudeva and Rohini] also had a daughter by name chitra, who is renowned by the name of lady subhadra, the wife of arjuna..