# How was Subhadrā born? What is the story of her birth?

Tags: mahabharata, subhadra

How was Subdhadrā, the sister of Kr̥ṣṇa born? In TV serial, it was shown that Kaṁsa wanted to kill one girl child of Devakī. But that girl child, flew into air, appeared as Durgā and reprimanded Kaṁsa for his sins. Durgā was later shown as Subhdhara.

How was she born as Subhadrā and what's the story of her birth other than what's already stated ? Is Subadhrā the child of Vasudeva's second wife or was she an avatāra of goddess Pārvatī since Pārvatī is the sister of Viṣṇu?

Comment: Subhadrā is the daughter of Rohiṇī and Vasudeva. She is Kr̥ṣṇa's half-sister technically, and isn't Devakī's biological child.

Comment: In Ādi Parva 221.17: *This is my sister, O Pārtha, and born of the same mother as Sāraṇa (this refers to Rohiṇī, the mother of Sāraṇa). May you be blessed. Her name is Bhadrā and she is the favorite daughter of my father.)*  This is where Kr̥ṣṇa first personally introduced Subhadrā to Arjuna. 

In Harivaṁśa (1.35.5-6) it is stated that: *Vasudeva begat on Rohiṇī his eldest son Rāma, Śāraṇa, Śāṭha, Durdama, Damana, Śvābhra, Piṇḍāraka, Kuśīnara, and a daughter by name Citrā. O descendant of Kuru, it was Citrā who passed by the name of Subhadrā.*

Comment: Also whether she is an avatāra or not, there are differing opinions. Someone already asked a question regarding it and it has some answers https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35836/24460
Some say Subhadrā is Yogamāya, some say she's Mahāmāya while some say she is bhakti svarūpa
https://gosai.com/writings/the-case-of-subhadra

Answer (score 1):

Subhadra was the daughter of Vasudeva and Rohini. As for the verses its given in comments only so m not repeating it.

As for whise avatara was she.:

**Brahma Vaivarta Purana Sri Radha-Krsna-samvada.:**

> *184. Agni will partially incarnate as noble and powerful Dhrstadyumna. **Satarupa will partially incarnate as Subhadra.***

So, she is the incarnation of Shatarupa (Manu's wife).

The name Manu means Man and Arjuna was the incarnation of Nara Maharishi. The name Nara also means Man. Just relating the names here.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..